# how to write expression in SSIS variable to trim the file name after specific character

Tags: ssis, integration, ssis-2012

I have created a variable  and writing an expression in SSIS variable to rename a file.

I have a file name like 'Filetodeploy_2014_05_01' I need to trim the characters after '_' (ie date) and display as 'Filetodeploy'

How can i build the above expression in a variable ?

thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? The expression as such is easy if its fixed length.

Comment: Looking through the [functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141671.aspx) do any of them sound promising?

Comment: i am new to SSIS ,In SSIS we don't have charindex So confused,but the following expression worked for me  'SUBSTRING(  @[User::FileName], 1, FINDSTRING(@[User::FileName],"_",1) - 1) '

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SUBSTRING( @[User::UDV_FileName] , 1, FINDSTRING( @[User::UDV_FileName] , "_",1 ) )
```

Also make it property true 'EvaluateAsExpression'